# Creating a new column in a DataFrame that adds 1 if a condition is met in other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am currently trying to create a new column (let's call it col C) within a dataframe that adds one to each row value if that same row has a value in another column that is greater than or less than a specified criteria.

So if the criteria is value in column A >2 and value in column B >= 4 column C looks as follows:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

Ive tried creating separate dataframes of the rows that meet each criteria and then dropping the ones that don't from the dataframe but there has to be a much simpler way.

Comment: Have you already tried to use something like `df['Column C'] = np.where( yourComplexCondition, valueIfConditionIsTrue, valueIfConditionIsFalse)`?? Consider that within that `yourComplexCondition` you can access to the other columns of the dataframe like `df['Column A']`

Comment: Why is in in the first line column `C` 1 and in the last line it's `0`. But both times none of the criteria match so both times A is not > 2 and B is not > 4. Still don't get what the value in C should represent.

Comment: I fixed it to >=4, column c should represent the number of columns where that row meets the column-specific criteria. Thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below either of the 2 snippets:

**Mostly prefer 2nd snippet**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data= [[1,4],[3,1],[4,5],[1,1]], columns=['a','b'])

df['c'] = np.where(((df['a']>2) & (df['b']>=4)), 2, 0)
df['c'] = np.where((((df['a']>2) | (df['b']>=4))&(df['c']==0)), 1, df['c'])
print(df)
```

OR

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data= [[1,4],[3,1],[4,5],[1,1]], columns=['a','b'])
df['c'] = 0
df['c'] = np.where((df['a']>2), df['c']+1, df['c'])
df['c'] = np.where((df['b']>=4), df['c']+1, df['c'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Ok so im a little confused because as I see it there if a row does not fall within both criteria the value of that row in col C becomes 1 but 1 is supposed to represent it only meeting the criteria in 1 col. A val of 1 in that code could be either it only meets criteria in one column of in none, none should be 0. Thank you.

Comment: I just tried it and it did not work :/ @Vaibhav

Comment: @AlbitCaban check the updated answer. This will work as per your requirement.

Comment: @AlbitCaban I have pasted 2 solutions as per your requirement. Both will give same result. Mostly prefer the 2nd one.

Comment: the second one worked fine! Thank you so much for your help! @Vaibhav

Comment: @AlbitCaban Cool :-)

Comment: @AlbitCaban cool. If this is your solution you were looking for then can you upvote and mark this as answer to your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can also do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data= [[1,4],[3,1],[4,5],[1,1]], columns=['a','b'])

df = df.assign(c=(df.a>2).astype(int)+(df.b>=4).astype(int))

>>> df
'''
   a  b  c
0  1  4  1
1  3  1  1
2  4  5  2
3  1  1  0
```